# TripleDES encryption working fine in java but not in c#

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, encryption

i am facing weak key error while doing tripleDES encryption.Code working fine in java but giving error in C# .net.

i have java code in which TripleDES ecryption is working fine i need to convert my java code in c#.i am facing Weak key error during conversion.Below both java and c# code given.

1) Java Code

```
public class TripleDES {
    private DESedeKeySpec desKeySpec;

    public TripleDES(String key) {
        try {
            byte[] keyBytes = { (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02,
                    (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02,
                    (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02,
                    (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02,
                    (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02,
                    (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02};



            this.desKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] origData) {
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
            SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(this.desKeySpec);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return cipher.doFinal(origData);
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] crypted) {
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
            SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(this.desKeySpec);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");  //DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            return cipher.doFinal(crypted);
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TripleDES des = new TripleDES("");

      byte[] data = { (byte)0x04, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x05, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFB, (byte)0xA6, (byte)0x66, (byte)0xCF};
      //byte[] data = { (byte)0x04, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x15, (byte)0xAF, (byte)0xFD, (byte)0xD8, (byte)0x88, (byte)0xBB};  


//-----------------Edited-----------------
String text = new BigInteger(1, data).toString(16);
System.out.println("Before encryption = " +text);             
    byte[] crypted = des.encrypt(data);
String text1 = new BigInteger(1, crypted).toString(16);
    System.out.println("Encrypted = " +text1);
byte[] decrypted = des.decrypt(crypted);
String text2 = new BigInteger(1, decrypted).toString(16);
    System.out.println("Decrypted = " +text2);
    }

}
```

2) C# Code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String Data = EncryptDES("041205FFFBA666CF");
    }

    public static string EncryptDES(string InputText)
    {
        byte[] key = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02 };
        byte[] clearData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InputText);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        TripleDES alg = TripleDES.Create();
        alg.Key = key;
        alg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] CipherBytes = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        cs.Close();
        string EncryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes);
        return EncryptedData;

    }
```

Key: 02020202020202020202020202020202

Data : 041205FFFBA666CF

Result : A334C92CEC163D9F

Can anyone please write code in c# which produce result same as java.

Comment: You want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Usually when someone is getting an error, the smart thing to do when asking about it is to tell us what the error is... preferably with a stack trace, if it comes with one.

Comment: The error the user is experiencing is a CryptographicException with the message _Specified key is a known weak key for 'TripleDES' and cannot be used_.  The problem here is that the key is considered 'weak' (as it should be) by the .Net framework and therefore it will not be usable.  There is no way to force .Net to use this key for TripleDES, unfortunately, even when just being used for Decryption.

Comment: Your key is reducing the algorithm to single DES (02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02). Just switch to DES instead of TripleDES.

Comment: @bartonjs can you please provide me working code?

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, I want to say that I *do not recommend* or endorse you to follow this way for forcing TripleDES to use a key it thinks is weak, however, given that you are using it for Decryption only, here is a way to do it using Reflection.

Firstly, you must 'force' the `TripeDES` class to take the weak key you want to use.  To do this, we use Reflection to bypass the check for a weak key that is performed when you attempt to set the key (`alg.Key = key`) and set the member variable directly:

```
//alg.Key = key; - THIS IS REPLACED BY THE BELOW
FieldInfo keyField = alg.GetType().GetField("KeyValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
keyField.SetValue(alg, key);
```

The key value of `TripleDES` will now be set to your weak key (`alg.Key`);

Next you have a minor mistake, in that you have forgotten to turn off padding:

```
alg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
alg.Padding = PaddingMode.None; // Add this, as the default padding is PKCS7
```

Finally, there will be a further check for a weak key when creating the Decryptor, so we must use Reflection again to bypass the check and create the ICryptoTransform:

```
// Comment out the below line and use the code below
// CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
ICryptoTransform Decryptor;
MethodInfo createMethod = alg.GetType().GetMethod("_NewEncryptor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
Decryptor = createMethod.Invoke(alg, new object[] { alg.Key, alg.Mode, alg.IV, alg.FeedbackSize, 1 }) as ICryptoTransform;
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```

The code will now run and accept weak keys, and perform the decryption you are looking for.

However, it does not look to me that the output is what you are expecting:

```
?Data
"4aU3DcHkiCTEywpiewWIow=="
```

At least now though you are able to use whichever key you want with `TripleDES`.

Answer (score 0):

A 3DES key is a 24-byte value which is broken down two three 8-byte values: `key0`, `key1`, `key2`.

Because 3DES is DES_Encrypt(key2, DES_Decrypt(key1, DES_Encrypt(key0, data))) any time `key1` is equal to `key2` or `key0` the algorithm is reduced to DES.  This is what .NET's TripleDES is warning you about.

The proper test here should account for clearing (or setting, or fixing) the parity bits in each byte, but a hand-waved version is:

```
SymmetricAlgorithm alg;
IEnumerable<byte> key0 = key.Take(8);
IEnumerable<byte> key1 = key.Skip(8).Take(8);
IEnumerable<byte> key2 = key.Skip(16);

if (key0.SequenceEquals(key1))
{
    alg = DES.Create();
    alg.Key = key2.ToArray();
}
else if (key1.SequenceEquals(key2))
{
    alg = DES.Create();
    alg.Key = key0.ToArray();
}
else
{
    alg = TripleDES.Create();
    alg.Key = key;
}
```

To replace your two liner:

```
TripleDES alg = TripleDES.Create();
alg.Key = key;
```